# Cant append dynamically created lineargradient to defs tag with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hey I'm trying to have different linear gradients for multiple parts in my line chart depending on some data. For that I'm creating multiple  tags in my init function:

```
var defs = self.svg.append("defs");

self.gradient = defs.data(self.data)
    .enter()
    .append('lineargradient')
    .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return 'svgGradient_' + i;
     })
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");

self.gradient.append("stop")
    .attr('class', 'start')
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "yellow")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

self.gradient.append("stop")
    .attr('class', 'end')
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", 'red')
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

In my update function I change the stop-color depending on the data values:

```
d3.selectAll('linearGradient>stop.end')
    .data(self.data)
    .attr('stop-color', function (d) {
        return self.colorScale(d.current);
    });
```

That code does successfully create multiple linear gradient and updates the color for the right value. By creating the line parts I set the stroke to the URL of the specific linear gradient like this:

```
.attr('stroke', function (d, i) {
        return 'url(#svgGradient_' + i + ')';
    })
```

Looking in the result it seems like it has the right URL for each line part. But here lies my problem that the linear gradient tags aren't children of the defs tag how they supposed to be and are children of the html tag instead. The line parts also don't have any stroke color, even though they link to the right linear gradient tag. Could the problem be that the tags aren't under the defs tag?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The gradient elements don't technically *need* to be in the `<defs>` element. But they absolutely do need to be inside the `<svg>` element.

Comment: Sadly they also aren't in the <svg> element.

Comment: Create a functioning [MCVE], so we can look at your code properly.